# Button toggle-class remains active upon pressing another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm writing a Greasemonkey script and having a problem setting the active states for two buttons I'm adding, each for toggling.

I've added code to assign class. The problem occurs when switching buttons.

For instance, when I press ***Button A***, it becomes active.  But then, if I press ***Button B,*** ***Button A*** remains active. Thereby leaving me with two buttons in an active state.

I know I can remove the active class by pressing my active button again prior going to another button. However I would like to achieve a function whereby, if *Button A* is active, and I press *Button B*, then *Button A* loses its active class, and vice versa.

Here is the code I'm using that's assigning class to my buttons:

```
$('#ButtonA').toggle(function () { 
    $("#ButtonA").addClass("active"); }, function () {
    $("#ButtonA").removeClass("active");
});

$('#ButtonB').toggle(function () {
    $("#ButtonB").addClass("active"); }, function () {
    $("#ButtonB").removeClass("active"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add one line in your first callback for each button to remove active class from any active button.

```
$('#ButtonA').toggle(function() {
    $('button.active').click(); // Remove active class from any active button.
    // you may adapt 'button.active' to select the proper buttons
    $('#ButtonA').addClass("active");
}, function() {
    $('#ButtonA').removeClass("active");
});​
```

**But,** use only one block of code for all the buttons, like this;

```
$('#ButtonA, #ButtonB, #ButtonC').toggle(function() { // this refer to the just clicked button.
    $('button.active').click(); // Remove active class from all other buttons.
    $(this).addClass("active");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

instead of copying and pasting.

See http://jsfiddle.net/fNtPP/1/ for a clean refactored code showing an example with 3 buttons.

Comment: Your fiddle code is an acceptable answer; you should have shown that *here* as well as at the third-party site.  However, not sure using `click()` like that is the best way to remove the old class.  It may cause side-effects with the rest of the target-page and/or GM script.

Comment: Thanks to all. I used Stouffi's code and it worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why you are using toggle like that, and avoid [***CloneAndModifyProgramming***](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CloneAndModifyProgramming) as much possible.

Add a class to your buttons, like so:

```
$("#ButtonA, #ButtonB, #ButtonC").addClass ("MyRadioBtns");
```

Then use `click` to handle the active state:

```
$("button.MyRadioBtns").click ( function (zEvent) {
    $("button.MyRadioBtns").removeClass ("active");
    var jThis   = $(this);
    jThis.addClass ("active");

    //- DO WHATEVER ELSE IS DESIRED WITH jThis HERE.
} );
```

[**See the code in action at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PSuMf/).